# Approval action- reassigning the task to the approver that made a mistake during approval process

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, approval-process, workflow-tasks-list

I have used the action Approval process in the Sharepoint designer.
I am using the approval process to validated a lost item with multiple people. The approvers are determine in the list column.

I am now wondering if there is a chance that I can modify the workflow to be able to reassign the task once it has already been completed. To explain in more detail, since i have multiple approvers for one list item multiple tasks will be created for each approval. I have encountered a problem here if one of the approvers makes a mistake. If i restart the approval process another task will be created for all approvers, not only the one that made a mistake. How can i fix that once the task is already approved/rejected i can reassign it to the same approval without having to create new tasks for the same list item.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature like Re-Assign a task in SharePoint designer workflow.

I suggest you assign a new task to the certain user that made a mistake.